# How to solve "Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault" when import cartopy?

Tags: python-3.x, segmentation-fault, spyder, cartopy

I am using Spyder 5.3.3 with python 3.10. And I want to import cartopy but I just got following errors:

```
import cartopy


Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault


Main thread:
Current thread 0x00000001105ae600 (most recent call first):
  File "/Users/xushan/opt/anaconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 54 in __init__
  File "/Users/xushan/opt/anaconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cartopy/crs.py", line 2904 in __init__
  File "/Users/xushan/opt/anaconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cartopy/crs.py", line 2926 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/xushan/opt/anaconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cartopy/__init__.py", line 107 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027 in _find_and_load
  File "/var/folders/sk/q1bd_nkn1z345sbmdty96hpn6_w5dn/T/ipykernel_26154/823226011.py", line 1 in <module>


Restarting kernel...
```

what happens and what can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: gross! that's a nasty bug. it's probably due to incompatible non-python dependencies in your environment. I would delete your environment and re-create it using a single channel, e.g. `conda env remove -n py310` and then `conda create -n py310 -c conda-forge python=3.10 cartopy gdal geopandas [...]` with all the packages you want.

Comment: while you're at it, I'd remove anaconda entirely - it fills your base env with a bunch of packages from the `defaults` channel which are incompatible with `conda-forge`. it's best to keep your base env lean, as you can get conflicts leading to nasty things like this if you're missing a package in your active env but it's present in your base env. so I'd recommend going with something like [`miniforge`](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge), a conda-forge-first no-base-env version of `anaconda`, or [`mambaforge`](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge), a faster variant

Comment: Thanks! I re-install conda environment several times...the lastest time is that, I can run my code, but just one time...the second time I ran it, it broke and returned the error message like below...

Comment: interesting - can you share the conda command(s) you run to create an env that produces this error? if this is reproducible it could be a bug for the conda recipe.

Comment: also - I assume this doesn't have anything to do with spider but it's worth confirming - can you activate the env and import cartopy from the terminal?

Comment: I just deleted the conda environment and re-install the anaconda because I have so many packages in base...for the conda commands to create the env, I am using: ```conda create --name py310 python=3.10```

Comment: for the spider: yes I also think it has nothing to do with Spyder. But I need to use Spyder to run under py310 environment to use python 3.10, in case of using the latest pandas package. The Spyder of base is using python 3.7...so I just tried with ```conda install spyder``` under this environment...that's why I mentioned Spyder.

Comment: you installed anaconda though? anaconda *comes* with lots of packages in base, so there's no way to use anaconda without lots of packages in there. you can always create an env with all the anaconda distribution packages using miniconda, e.g. with `conda create -n anaconda -c defaults anaconda`. but tbh I can't really help you if you install `conda-forge` packages using anaconda.

Comment: ah I don't know it...I thought I need to install anaconda to use the command ```conda```...

Comment: but for installing packages, I am using ```conda install``` or pip install...

Comment: now I am trying ```conda create -n py310 -c conda-forge python=3.10 cartopy gdal geopandas numpy matplotlib spyder spyder-kernels```

Comment: it works! Thanks @MichaelDelgado. I think it might be because there are too many packages in base...

Comment: there are a number of different ways to install `conda`. you can install `miniconda` or `miniforge`, which don't put anything in your base env, or you can install `anaconda`, which is miniconda + a default base env stuffed with packages from  the `deafults` channel. this is nice if you're just getting started, but it starts to wreak havoc when you want to use packages from other channels. so I'd recommend one of these lighter weight installs, or [`mambaforge`](//github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge), which installs `mamba`, a compiled version of `conda` written in C++ to be much faster.

Comment: How to deal with this in docker ?